# ANTLR: How to allow boolean values in arithmetic operations

Tags: javascript, boolean, antlr

I am trying to write ANTLR grammar for reading JavaScript arithmetic operations.

Specifically, I want to support boolean values in arithmetic operations such as `0 + true = 1` and `0 + false = 0`.

I have the following right now:

```
BOOLEAN: 'true'
       | 'false';
```

How can I make `1` also mean "true", and "0" also mean false?

Answer (score 1):

> How to allow boolean values in arithmetic operations

By making `BOOLEAN` one possible alternative for your expression rule. In fact, this will already be the case if you wrote your grammar the normal way. Something like `0 + true` is syntactically valid in virtually any language that supports infix operators (it'd be a type error in many languages, but still syntactically valid).

> How can I make 1 also mean "true", and "0" also mean false?

By treating it as such in your type checking, code generation and/or evaluation code. The grammar doesn't specify what things mean - only what is and isn't syntactically valid and what the resulting parse tree will look like.